# Can't delete a file using IO or NIO while file exists

Tags: java, io, nio

In a first method I create a file that i need to delete after it has been processed. For this I use an input stream. After treatment, the file, named fileSrc has to be deleted from hard drive.

I tried two different way to delete the file.

```
public File signPDF(File fileSrc) {
    // signature process ... 

    boolean isDeleted = fileSrc.delete();
    boolean isFileExist = fileSrc.exists();
    logger.info("Is file exist ? - " + isFileExist);
    if(isDeleted) {
        logger.info("File has been deleted");
    } else {
        logger.warn("File could not be deleted");
    }
    // try to delete on java exit
    Path path = Paths.get(fileSrc.toString());
    try {
        isFileExist = Files.deleteIfExists(path);
        logger.info("File has been deleted with NIO: " + isFileExist);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //deleting file failed
        logger.warn("File could not be deleted with NIO: " + isFileExist);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return signedFile
}
```

In my log, i note that the file is not deleted.
I donwload the file copying an inputstream in another method. Classically:

```
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, targetFile);
```

I tried several methods to close the connection and the inputStream

```
 IOUtils.close(con);
 inputStream.close();
 IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
```

None of those methods work unfortunatelly.

Note to complete : This issue was solved modifying the file path (uncorrect) thanks to @GyroGearless. Finally I met a second issue. THe file was deleted before being handled.
I solved this with this code snippet :

```
File toDelete = new File(fileSrc + File.separator + docId + ".pdf");
try {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    logger.error("InterruptedException "  + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
toDelete.deleteOnExit();
```

Comment: Did you close your file ? `fileSrc.close();`

Comment: File in java.io.File do not have a close method... But i close the inputstream that retrieve the data for the file.

Comment: Could you please provide the output of `printStackTrace()`?

Comment: FWIW, to make a `Path` from a `File`, just use `fileSrc.toPath()`

Comment: @davidvera let me reword myself, did you close every `InputStream` you mentionned (and did not provide) ?

Comment: @IQbrod yes i closed them.

Comment: @GyroGearless I should have logged all this before. the path was not pointing to the file.

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons why you cannot delete the file first when it is open by another application or if your application does not have permission to delete the file.

Comment: And a third option is that my path was not correct. It was my case :)